# Recursive method for checking an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I have created a constructor that I am attempting to prototype. I want a method that checks through each property in an object to see if its empty and if it is it returns the key. If the property is an object I want it to check through that sub object as well.

**UPDATED:**

My code thus far:

```
function Properties(val1, val2, val3, val4){
    this.prop1 = val1 || "";
    this.prop2 = val2 || "";
    this.prop3 = val3 || "";
    this.prop4 = val4 || {};
}

Properties.prototype = {
    isEmpty: function(){
        for (key in this) {
            if(typeof this[key] == "object" && this[key] !== null){
                this[key].isEmpty();
            } else {
                if(!this[key]){
                    console.log(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var test = new Properties("Something", "", "", {subProp1: "Something Else", subProp2: "",   subProp3: {subSubProp1: "", subSubProp2: "" }});
```

The method should return prop2, prop3, subProp2, subSubProp1, subSubProp2

Comment: What does this have to do with constructors and prototypes? A function detecting empty dictionaries (objects) much better stands on its own. You rarely want to check through the properties of instances of a "class". Can you please show your complete code (including the constructor, the prototype assignment, the instance creation and the method call), as well as elaborate your use case?

Comment: Why do you expect the method to exist on the subobject? Where does your subobject come from?

Comment: Yeah thanks, but imo it's quite obvious that those objects you are passing to the constructor (to become properties) are *no instances of `Properties`*, and won't have a `.isEmpty()` method. Pass `new Properties("Something Else", "", …)` instead.

Comment: Maybe were on a different page, but another user answered my question. Thanks for your attempt though

Comment: I've seen that, it's the reason why I only commented and not attempted an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method isn't a property on the object. You need to pass in the object in question. You can also pass an array in to keep track of the empty keys:

```
var emptyKeys = [];
function isEmpty(obj, keysArr) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            isEmpty(obj[key], keysArr);
        } else {
            if (obj[key] == "" || obj[key] == null) {
                keysArr.push(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/17rt0qy3/1/

If you want this on the actual object, simply add the above function inside the `isEmpty` function:

```
isEmpty: function(){
    var emptyKeys = [];
    amIEmpty(this, emptyKeys);

    return emptyKeys;

    //Actual logic
    function amIEmpty(obj, keysArr) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (key == "isEmpty") {
                continue;
            }

            if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                amIEmpty(obj[key], keysArr);
            } else {
                if (obj[key] == "" || obj[key] == null) {
                    keysArr.push(key);
                }
            }
        }         
    }
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/17rt0qy3/2/

And a fiddle working with your demo object above: http://jsfiddle.net/17rt0qy3/3/

Aaand another edit, <strike>this will only `log` the keys, but</strike> it's a bit cleaner:

```
isEmpty: function(obj, keys) {
    keys = keys || [];
    obj = obj || this;
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.isEmpty(obj[key], keys)
        } else {
            if (obj[key] == "" || obj[key] == null) {
                keys.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    return keys;
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/17rt0qy3/8/

Comment: The method is a property of the object. I am prototyping the constructor class.

Comment: This works but I feel like there is a cleaner way. I have written recursive functions before but none as a prototype and I feel like I should be able to use this inside the recursion rather than passing it to another function inside the method

Comment: @ChrisJ -- I got an idea, give me a few mins

Comment: @ChrisJ -- Added a "cleaner" answer...maybe.

Comment: @ChrisJ -- No problem! In case you missed the edit, I made it return the empty keys as well :D

Comment: The method name is "isEmpty" implying it returns a boolean. I think the logic should be changed to break as soon as a non-empty value was found, returning `true`